# Magento 2 conditionally hide quantity box

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I would like to hide the built in quantity box based on whether i have set a custom attribute for quantity. Some products that dont have a custom attribute for quantity will need to still display the quantity box. I'd like this for everywhere the quantity box is shown, but most importantly and where i am currently trying to get it to work is the product page. For example, one of the products i will have is business cards. I will have a price per each variant (material, number of sides, quantity, lamination etc) which i can create using the custom attributes and this part works fine.

I cannot work out how to do the checking for the custom attribute called quantity. I have tried various things and when i do a var_dump of the variable i just get "NULL" and im not sure where i am going wrong. I am using Magento 2.3 and i am editing the addtocart.phtml template file, which i was hoping to just add an if statement to not show the qty div if it returned true.

The code i have last tried is:

```
<?php $myquantity = $_product->getCustomAttribute('quantity'); ?>
```

and when i do a var_dump i just get NULL.
The full addtocart.phtml code is with the only changes are the line above and the var_dump line:

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $myquantity = $_product->getCustomAttribute('quantity'); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
        <?php var_dump($myquantity); ?>
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am only at the checkign phase so far, i didnt see the point in trying to write the if statement when i can't return the right information first.
Of course, if there is another/better way i can do this i would appreciate the help. I am not much of a developer so i was hoping for a simple resolution.

Thanks

Comment: What is code of your attribute ?

Comment: Attribute code is quantity

Answer (score 0):

If issue is related to get attribute value, You can use:

```
<?php $myquantity = $_product->getQuantity(); ?>

----------OR----------

<?php $myquantity = $_product->getAttributeText('quantity'); ?>
```

once you have value of `$myquantity`, you can put your logic.

Hope above will help!

**Update I**

You can create a `Yes/No` type attribute instead of `drop-down`.
Default value will be `No`. for product you want to hide add to cart change value to `Yes`.

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('quantity'); ?>
```

Will give you value `Yes Or No`, based on value you can put your logic!

Comment: No, that doesnt work either. With the first line i get NULL still and the second line i get bool(false).

Comment: Does your attribute set `yes` for  `used in product listnig`

Comment: Yes, "used in product listing" is set to yes.

Comment: Have you added any value in admin for this product ?

Comment: yes, it is a dropdown with 2 values. I want to check if this dropdown exists when the page is loaded, before any value is selected. I guess i want a boolean answer so i can do an if statement if the attribute is true or false

Comment: @Alex, have you checked my updates ?

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on a similar task. You should just need to add "getValue()"

`<?php $myquantity = $_product->getCustomAttribute('quantity')->getValue(); ?>`